# How does this happen? AssertionError: Response redirected to 'http://testserver/account/signin/', expected 'http://testserver/accounts/signin/'

Tags: django, django-testing

This just doesn't make any sense to me, how can the assertion fail when the arguments are identical?

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_register_page_redirects_to_signin_page (forum.tests.test_views.ForumTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Bryan/work/osqa/forum/tests/test_views.py", line 19, in test_register_page_redirects_to_signin_page
    self.assertRedirects(response, '/accounts/signin/')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/test/testcases.py", line 345, in assertRedirects
    (url, expected_url))
AssertionError: Response redirected to 'http://testserver/account/signin/', expected 'http://testserver/accounts/signin/'
```

Here is the test:

```
class ForumTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_register_page_redirects_to_signin_page(self):
        response = self.client.get('/account/register/', follow=True)
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/accounts/signin/')
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, "auth/signin.html")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: +1 - I've been there, I feel your pain

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're not entirely identical... are you sure that this line

```
self.assertRedirects(response, '/accounts/signin/')
```

shouldn't be

```
self.assertRedirects(response, '/account/signin/')
```

?

Answer (score 6):

Because your arguments... **aren't** identical?

```
http://testserver/account/signin/
http://testserver/accounts/signin/
                         ^
```